# Wordpress website navigation menu not working in page but working in post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting problem with navigation menu in my wordpress website. This is my first project in wordpress so i don't know this question is relevant or not.

My navigation menu is properly working when i open any post but after entering to any pages, menu is not clickable except 'home' menu.Is there any who can help me to face with this issue ?

I am using wordpress default theme "scaffold".

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: Please share website link..?

Comment: @Top-Bot  i can n't post because it is in my localhost machine and isn't hosted yet.